# Timetable Stats PHP Page

Tags: php, mysql

I have a field called `dPostTime`, which has the date and time stored of an entry.

If I wanted to create a page that showed me the number of entries per hour, would I need to have 24 queries, one for each hour, or what's the best way to do this.

I'd like the chart to appear as follows:

```
5-6pm - 24 posts
6-7pm - 56 posts
7-8pm - 34 posts
8-9pm - 35 posts
```

etc......

Comment: Do you want to include results for hours with no records (E.g. 4-5pm - 0 posts) or only the results for the hours that have records?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL doesn't have recursive functionality, so you're left with using the NUMBERS table trick -

1. Create a table that only holds incrementing numbers - easy to do using an auto_increment:

   ```
   DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `example`.`numbers`;
   CREATE TABLE  `example`.`numbers` (
     `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
      PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
   ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
   ```
2. Populate the table using:

   ```
   INSERT INTO NUMBERS
     (id)
   VALUES
     (NULL)
   ```

   ...for as many values as you need.
3. Use [DATE_ADD](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add) to construct a list of dates, increasing the days based on the NUMBERS.id value.  Replace "2010-01-01" and "2010-01-02" with your respective start and end dates (but use the same format, YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS) -

   ```
   SELECT x.dt
     FROM (SELECT DATE_FORMAT(DATE_ADD('2010-01-01', INTERVAL (n.id - 1) HOUR), '%H:%i') AS dt
             FROM numbers n
            WHERE DATE_ADD('2010-01-01', INTERVAL (n.id - 1) HOUR) <= '2010-01-02' ) x
   ```
4. LEFT JOIN onto your table of data based on the datetime portion.

   ```
      SELECT x.dt,
             COALESCE(COUNT(a.dPostTime), 0) AS numPerHour
        FROM (SELECT DATE_FORMAT(DATE_ADD('2010-01-01', INTERVAL (n.id - 1) HOUR), '%H') AS dt
                FROM numbers n
               WHERE DATE_ADD('2010-01-01', INTERVAL (n.id - 1) HOUR) <= '2010-01-02' ) x x
   LEFT JOIN YOUR_TABLE a ON DATE_FORMAT(a.dPostTime, '%H') = x.dt 
    GROUP BY x.dt
    ORDER BY x.dt
   ```

### Why Numbers, not Dates?

Simple - dates can be generated based on the number, like in the example I provided.  It also means using a single table, vs say one per data type.

Comment: By recursive functionality, do you mean that MySQL cannot use a Connect by level like Oracle can?  I have had this exact question answered for Oracle: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3455739/how-to-select-records-grouped-by-the-hour-of-the-day-including-hours-that-have-no

Comment: @Cyntech: Correct, `CONNECT BY` is Oracle specific hierarchical query syntax.  The recursive WITH is now ANSI standard, but Oracle didn't support it until 11gR2--in Oracle's defense, they've had `CONNECT BY` since v2.

Comment: Thanks for this. Is this the only way to go about this? I have a single field that captures the date and time. I was going to use PHP to display this in a chart

Comment: @BigMike: You need to generate a sequential list of hours to LEFT JOIN against.  If it's a one time affair, use UNION statements to derive the table you need.

Comment: Thanks, could you explain #2 again? how many numbers do I need?

Comment: @BigMike: You'd need to run the INSERT statement 24 -- one for every hour in the day.

Answer (score 0):

```
  SELECT COUNT(*),
         HOUR(`dPostTime`) AS `hr`
    FROM `table`
GROUP BY `hr`
```

After that in php format `hr` to be equal `'hr - 1' - hr`

Comment: Only issue I see is if the OP wants to see that there's a zero count, because there aren't values for the hour in the column.